# Math Competition Question for IMC 2016 (University level)

Tags: functions, optimization, continuity, contest-math

I am practicing for the IMC math competition for university students, and I was wondering if someone could help me with this question:

> Today, Ivan the Confessor prefers continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ satisfying $f(x)+f(y)\geq |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in [0,1]?$ Find the minimum of $\int_0^1 f$ over all preferred functions.

This is from the 2016 IMC, question 7.

My idea was to integrate on both sides from 1 to 0 twice, the first integral in x and the second in y, but this gave a solution of 1/6, but the solution says the true answer is 1/4. I was wondering if someone could explain why my answer was incorrect, and if anyone has a solution to this problem?

Comment: Your method assumes there is a function such that $f(x)+f(y) = |x-y|$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]$.  This function cannot exist. (Check $x=y$, and then $x\neq y$)

Comment: I'm guessing the best $f$ is $f(x)=\left|x-\frac12\right|.$

Comment: All you've shown us that $\int f\geq \frac16.$ But you haven't shown you can get $\frac16.$

Comment: The inequality implies $2f(x)\geq |2x-1|,$ so you certainly can't do better

Comment: How did you get the inequality 2f(x) >|2x-1|?

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1279762p6727193 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%2Bf(y)%5Cgeq%20%7Cx-y%7C%24)

Answer (score 7):

Take $y=1-x$. Then $f(x) + f(1-x) \geq |2x-1|$, so $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx + \int_0^1 f(1-x)dx \geq \int_0^1 |2x-1| dx = \frac{1}{2}.$$

However, using the substitution $u=1-x$, one can see that $\int_0^1 f(1-x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$. Therefore $\int_0^1 f(x) dx \geq \frac{1}{4}$. The equality occurs for the ''preferred'' function $f(x) = |x-\frac{1}{2}|$.